# Error in etc/sudoers.d/Nikhil Kumar Singh

Tags: sudo, etc

When I enter `sudo -s` or any `sudo` command I am getting an error like this

```
etc/sudoers.d/Nikhil Kumar Singh syntax error near line 1...
```

I have tried multiple things but nothing has resolved the issue...
Kindly help me out!

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version? Do you know if you have sudo access (are you using a computer shared by many users)? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1395030/edit) the question to add more information.

Comment: Are we going to guess what the content of /etc/sudoers.d/Nikhil Kumar Singh  ?Anyway, you can moved the file somewhere else and the error will go away.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I have installed ubuntu mate 18.04.02

Comment: @SorenA I am new to ubuntu could you please tell me how to move that file?, that file got created when I run /hardening.sh script, that ask my username and I provide it...Is moving that file won't create any issues?

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-18-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/23966 with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly.  Your system is now Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with MATE but still on-topic here.

Comment: "Nikhil Kumar Singh" is your human name. You should use your userid instead, as shown by `whoami`, `id`, `echo "$USER"`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the file...

In `terminal`:

`sudo mv /etc/sudoers.d/Nikhil* ~/Desktop`

or

`pkexec mv /etc/sudoers.d/Nikhil* ~/Desktop`

then

`reboot`

**For extra credit**:

In the `terminal`, do `cat ~/Desktop/Nikhil*` and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1395030/edit) that output into your original question.

Comment: Wow superb thanks a lot!!!!!! I tried almost 3 days to get it resolve...one slight correction I am not able to sudo so I used pkexec insted, but this command work like miracle!!!!! Thank you so much @heynnema

Comment: @Nikhilsingh Great news! Thanks for the update.